# MySQL - Relational/intermediary tables and JOIN queries?

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many, relational

Been reading up on this (for ages!) and can't get clear picture.

First, if I have two tables (e.g. recipes and ingredients) with a many-to-many relationship and I create a intermediary/relational table, how do I write an SQL query to to find all recipes with, say, bananas in them?

Second, why would I have this third relational table if I can find the same information using JOIN queries without the third tables creation??

Really appreciate a clear, helpful explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I write an SQL query to to find all recipes with, say, bananas in them?

You can do:

```
select distinct r.id, r.name
from recipe r
join recipe_ingredient ri on ri.id_recipe = r.id
join ingredient i on i.id = ri.id_ingredient
where i.name = 'banana'
```

> Second, why would I have this third relational table if I can find the same information using JOIN queries without the third tables creation?

Since a recipe can have **many** ingredients, and an ingredient can be related to **many** recipies the relationship between those two tables is not 1:n but n:m. Therefore, you need an intermediate table, as shown below:

```
create table recipe (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(20)
);

create table ingredient (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(20)
);

create table recipe_ingredient (
  id int primary key not null,
  id_recipe int not null,
  id_ingredient int not null,
  quantity double not null,
  foreign key fk1 (id_recipe) references recipe (id),
  foreign key fk2 (id_ingredient) references ingredient (id)
);
```

If an ingredient showed up in a single recipe always, the structure would be simpler, as you seem to think. This simpler structure would probably look like:

```
create table recipe (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(20)
);

create table ingredient (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(20),
  id_recipe int not null,
  foreign key fk3 (id_recipe) references recipe (id) 
);
```

A model like this one is not really practical in this case. You would end up having the same ingredient multiple times. For example, if a cake uses "flour" and bread uses "flour", then "flour" would end up twice in the ingredients table. Not a great idea.

Comment: Thanks for that! From my reading many articles I got the impression that an n:m relation can be queried using JOIN without an intermediate table. Or is it the case that you _must_ have an intermediate table if looking to query n:m relatable data?

Comment: Thanks @the-impaler, marked response as answer. And it makes more sense now after a few weeks coding. But in my comment question, it is true that you _must_ have linking/intermediate table to query n:m relatable data, correct?  Thanks

Comment: @Matthew Yes, the database model needs to have an intermediate third table to design an n:m relationship.